# How to filter html div using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Suppose,I have 10 cellphones in my store and, i want dynamically search them by entering their name.I want to filter out the cellphone including a link which will be telling the specifications of the cellphone.How can I design please help..

Comment: Show us your html and controller code. What error do you get ?

Comment: Too broad, please show us some code you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Actually The problem is that I am a new at angularjs I i just know how to filter data..I just want an basic idea about filtering a link or an image...

Comment: it is explained at the official site on the tutorial! :)

Comment: Agree with  Ceylan Mumun Kocabaş .

Comment: All is here... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you are not aware of angular , i am posting this answer, let me know if you need anything change, this is from what i understood from question..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  Type your phone from below model :  <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
    <br/>
    {{ [{
'name': 'iPhone7',
'brand': 'Apple',
'model': 'iPhone7'
}, {
'name': 'iPhone6',
'brand': 'Apple',
'model': 'iPhone6'
},] | filter:{'model': search } }}
<br/>
    <a id="link-6" ng-href="{{search}}"  ng-show="search">{{search}}</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks...Suppose I searched Iphone7.Now the iphone7 should contain a link which on clicking will take me to its specifications...thanks.

Comment: @Utsav I think you can search yourself... It is **a very basic** use of AngularJS what you are looking for. Jigar don't have to write all the code for you.

Comment: I agree with you @Mistalis , but as he said i am beginner in angular, that's why i have posted my answer even i wrote at there this. BTW i have updated my answer, let me know.

Comment: @UtsavPrasad : Everyhting won't be able to find exact as what we expect, need to suffer for that :)

Comment: Hmm.I know I just wanted that if i filtered iphone7..There should be a link....for eg....I want to put a link www.apple.com in it...

Comment: @UtsavPrasad : Now that **you have to do that** as i have provided a working sample , you have to just play around your self as other members said this is very basic thing, believe me you will learn something.